Duplicate Apple Internal Keyboard Appears in xinput List on Ubuntu 22.04 - Troubleshooting Help Needed
I'm experiencing an issue on my MacBook where the Apple Internal Keyboard appears twice in the xinput list on Ubuntu 22.04. Despite various attempts to resolve the issue, the duplicate entry persists. Below are the details and steps I've tried so far:
System Details:

Device: MacBook
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Kernel: 5.19.0-46-generic
Here is my actual kernel version: 5.15.0-118-generic

Issue Description:
When I run the xinput command, the Apple Internal Keyboard shows up twice:
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Laser Mouse                  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS2toUSB PS2toUSB Adapter Mouse           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS2toUSB PS2toUSB Adapter Consumer Control    id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ appletouch                                id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ PS2toUSB PS2toUSB Adapter                 id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ PS2toUSB PS2toUSB Adapter System Control  id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple Computer Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple Computer Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ PS2toUSB PS2toUSB Adapter Consumer Control    id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]

Steps I’ve Tried:

Disable One Instance via xinput:

I tried disabling one instance using xinput disable , but this does not resolve the duplicate issue.

Checking xkb Layout:

Ran setxkbmap -print -verbose 10 to inspect the keyboard layout, which confirmed fr layout with apple_laptop model, but didn’t provide insights into the duplication.
Modifying Udev Rules:

Created a custom Udev rule to disable one of the keyboards, but both still appear after reloading the rules and rebooting.

Exploring hid_apple Module Options:
Adjusted the options in /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf, followed by reloading the module, but the duplicate entry persists.

Checking Logs:
Reviewed the Gnome Shell and Udev logs (journalctl, dmesg), which didn't show any obvious errors related to the duplicate keyboard entries.


Request for Help:
I’m unsure how to proceed further. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or does anyone have suggestions on additional troubleshooting steps to try? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

5.19 is not a supported kernel in any version of Ubuntu. Where did this come from?

Hi Davis, you're right it's a mistake. Here is my actual kernel version: 5.15.0-118-generic
